# MYSQL Join if available

Tags: mysql

I have two tables I want to join, products and campaign_products
The tables look like this.

`TABLE product 
id | name`

`TABLE campaign_products
id | fk_campaign | fk_product | note`

and if it's of interest

`TABLE campaign
id | name`

In all cases I need all the products returned, and if there is a row in the campaign_products which matches then add the values of those columns in as well. (null otherwise).
Remembering that multiple products can be part of multiple campaigns. 
Here is what I tried, and in this case it only returns products that have a reference in campaign_products or products that don't exist at all in campaign_products so if the product is in campaign_products for another campaign it won't show up in other campaigns that don't include that product.

`SELECT 
product.id productId, 
product.name productName, 
campaign_product.note 
campaignProductNote 
FROM`product
`LEFT JOIN campaign_products ON product.id = campaign_products.fk_product 
WHERE campaign_products.fk_campaign = 2 OR campaign_products.fk_campaign IS NULL`

"2" changes based on the campaign being looked up.

I can't think of a way to solve this problem, is there a simple solution I'm missing ?

Comment: What is your output and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is move the condition in the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
product.id productId, 
product.name productName, 
campaign_product.note 
campaignProductNote 
FROM product
LEFT JOIN campaign_products ON product.id = campaign_products.fk_product 
AND (campaign_products.fk_campaign = 2 OR campaign_products.fk_campaign IS NULL)
```

Comment: why would it make a difference whether conditions are in the WHERE vs ON?

Comment: @SS781 Having that condition in the where clause affects all rows (from both table A and table B) This way the existence of B is not required to return a result.

Comment: I would never of thought of this... I had already got work around but it was so complex I didn't want to leave it in there. This is much better and much more readable. Thanks !